# Illegal datatype context when modelling round robin scheduler in Haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass, algebraic-data-types

I'm modelling a round robin scheduler in Haskell.

```
class Schedulable s where
  isFinal :: s -> Bool

class Scheduler s where
  add :: (Schedulable a) => a -> s -> s
  next :: (Schedulable a) => s -> (a, s)
  empty :: s -> Bool

data Schedulable a => RoundRobin = RoundRobin [a] [a]

instance Scheduler RoundRobin where
  add p (RoundRobin ps qs) = RoundRobin (ps ++ [p]) qs

  next (RoundRobin []     qs) = next (RoundRobin qs [])
  next (RoundRobin (p:ps) qs) = (p, RoundRobin ps (qs ++ [p]))

  empty (RoundRobin [] _) = True
  empty _                 = False
```

However, GHC complains that

```
main.hs:9:6:
    Illegal datatype context (use -XDatatypeContexts): Schedulable a =>
```

How can I solve this issue?

I also saw [a proposal about removing datatype contexts](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/NoDatatypeContexts), so how can I model the scheduler without using datatype contexts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `Scheduler` class

```
class Scheduler s where
  add :: (Schedulable a) => a -> s -> s
  next :: (Schedulable a) => s -> (a, s)
  empty :: s -> Bool
```

is not going to work.

`add` promises that values of any `Schedulable` type can be added to the scheduler. That is possible, but it requires an extension, `ExistentialQuantification` or `GADTs` would allow to define a type wrapping *any* `Schedulable` value.

`next`, however, promises to deliver a value of *any* `Schedulable` type, whatever the caller desires, and that's not going to work. If I only ever add `Int` values to the scheduler, and then ask for a `String`, how would it construct one out of thin air?

One way to get your code to work is

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
module Schedules where

class Schedulable s where
  isFinal :: s -> Bool

class Scheduler s where
  add :: (Schedulable a) => a -> s -> s
  next :: s -> (Schedule, s) -- returns a Schedulable item of unknown type, wrapped in a Schedule
  empty :: s -> Bool

-- Wrapper type for any Schedulable
data Schedule where
    Schedule :: Schedulable a => a -> Schedule

-- Equivalent alternative using existential quantification instead of GADT syntax
-- data Schedule = forall a. Schedulable a => Schedule a

-- make Schedules Schedulable, maybe not necessary
instance Schedulable Schedule where
    isFinal (Schedule s) = isFinal s

-- RoundRobin queues schedulable items, wrapped as Schedules, since lists are homogeneous
data RoundRobin = RoundRobin [Schedule] [Schedule]

-- How RoundRobin works
instance Scheduler RoundRobin where
  -- enqueue item after wrapping it
  add p (RoundRobin ps qs) = RoundRobin (ps ++ [Schedule p]) qs

  -- deliver next item to process
  -- the first equation suggests that (Maybe Schedule, s) would be the better return type
  next (RoundRobin []     []) = error "Nothing to schedule"
  next (RoundRobin []     qs) = next (RoundRobin qs [])
  next (RoundRobin (p:ps) qs) = (p, RoundRobin ps (qs ++ [p]))

  empty (RoundRobin [] _) = True
  empty _                 = False
```

Using `GADT` syntax or existential quantification makes the constraints imposed on the constructor available via pattern matching, in contrast to the old `DatatypeContexts` that despite the constraints on the type, required the context put on the functions using the type.

Answer (score 3):

Is not recommended to define constraints into `data` definitions (see [Learn Haskell...](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses)).

Is preferable set contraints into functions.

(You can, anyway, set DatatypeContexts modifier)

Comment: So do you have any suggestion about how can I improve my code?